# Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.elasticsearch.client.RestClientBuilder

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-search

```
An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

   org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.client.impl.DefaultElasticsearchClientFactory.createClient(DefaultElasticsearchClientFactory.java:92)

The following method did not exist:

    org.elasticsearch.client.RestClientBuilder.setMaxRetryTimeoutMillis(I)Lorg/elasticsearch/client/RestClientBuilder;

The method's class, org.elasticsearch.client.RestClientBuilder, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/home/temp/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.elasticsearch.client/elasticsearch-rest-client/7.10.2/d0c857275bcec532079cdabb7913e2611c123e70/elasticsearch-rest-client-7.10.2.jar!/org/elasticsearch/client/RestClientBuilder.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations: 
 
    org.elasticsearch.client.RestClientBuilder: 
        file:/home/temp/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.elasticsearch.client/elasticsearch-rest-client/7.10.2/d0c857275bcec532079cdabb7913e2611c123e70/elasticsearch-rest-client-7.10.2.jar

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.elasticsearch.client.RestClientBuilder*
```

We need to use elasticsearch version 7.10.2 and currently we are using springboot version 2.3.9

any help?

is this correct mapping in application.yaml file for elastic search 7.10.2

```
 hibernate:
    format_sql: true
    search.default:
      elasticsearch:
        dynamic_mapping: true
        index_schema_management_strategy: update
        required_index_status: yellow
```

https://stackoverflow.com/users/6692043/yrodiere

Answer (score 1):

The version of the `elasticsearch-rest-client` dependency (Elasticsearch's low-level REST client) does not have to match the version of Elasticsearch server you actually use. `elasticsearch-rest-client` 7.16.3 will talk just fine to Elasticsearch server 7.10.2. And elasticsearch-rest-client 7.16.3 is licensed under ASL 2.0, if that's what you're worried about.

So, in short: do what the Hibernate Search documentation suggests, and upgrade to the latest version of `elasticsearch-rest-client`. See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#gettingstarted-framework-spring-boot-dependency-versions :

> Spring Boot automatically sets the version of dependencies without your knowledge. While this is ordinarily a good thing, from time to time Spring Boot dependencies will be a little out of date. Thus, it is recommended to override Spring Boot’s defaults at least for some key dependencies.
>
> With Maven, add this to your POM’s :
>
> ```
> <properties>
>    <hibernate.version>5.6.5.Final</hibernate.version>
>    <elasticsearch.version>7.16.3</elasticsearch.version>
>    <!-- ... plus any other properties of yours ... -->
> </properties>
> ```

If you use Elasticsearch's high-level REST client, now... you're in a pickle. *That* client is no longer open-source and can cause licensing issues. And its last open-source version (7.10.something)  may not work with `elasticsearch-rest-client` 7.16.3. So if you really need to stick with version 7.10 or earlier of the high-level REST client, then you'll need to use older versions of `elasticsearch-rest-client` and Hibernate Search.